# Find most popular strings in a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, full-text-search

I am using MyISAM engine with fulltext indexing for storing a list of strings.

These strings can be a single word, or a sentence.

If I want to know how many times string `hello` appears in my table, I do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) Total 
    FROM String s
WHERE
    MATCH (s.name) AGAINST ('hello')
```

I would like to create a similar report, but for all strings. Result should be a list of TOP-N strings that are the most common in this table (top ones most probably are "the", "a", "to" etc.).

Exact match case is pretty obvious:

```
SELECT name as String, count(*) as Total
    FROM String
GROUP 
    BY name
ORDER
    BY total desc
LIMIT *some number*
```

But it counts only whole strings.

Is there any way to achieve my desired result?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not aware of any way to query the inverted index/dictionary to get the list of words in the data.  Perhaps someone else knows a secret way.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I guess, I won't find a way to achieve that using current approach. Would you suggest any other? Maybe I should move to systems like Solr or Sphinx? Basically, I am working with huge datasets, I store English strings and their translations to multiple languages. Later I am doing full text search on this dataset, providing some string, source and destination languages. Later I will need to do such reports, like I described in the question and some more analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any solution with SQL and my Full text index, but I managed to get my desired result by getting all of my strings from DB and processing them on the backend with php:

```
//get all strings from DB
$queryResult = $db->query("SELECT name as String FROM String");

//Combine all of them into array
while($row = $queryResult->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $stringArray[] = $row['String'];
}

//"Glue" all these strings into one huge string
$text = implode(" ", $stringArray);

//Make everything lowercase
$textLowercase = strtolower($text);

//Find all words
$result = preg_split('/[^a-z]/', $textLowercase, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

//Filter some unwanted words
$result = array_filter($result, function($x){
    return !preg_match("/^(.|the|and|of|to|it|in|or|is|a|an|not|are)$/",$x);
});

//Count a number of occurrence of each word
$result = array_count_values($result);

//Sort
arsort($result);

//Select TOP-N strings, where N is $amount
$result = array_slice($result, 0, $amount);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no easy way for this. I would create a "statistic table" for this purpose only. One column for words themselves, one column for the number of occurrences. (Primary key on the first column of course.)

For this with a PL/SQL block scanning all strings, and split them for words.
If the string is not found in the statistic table, you insert a new row.
If the string is found in the statistic table, you increase the value in the second column.

This can run for a pretty long time, but after the first run is ready, you only have to check the new strings on insert, perhaps with a trigger. (Assuming you want to use it not once but regularly.)

Hope this helps, I have no simpler answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think if you use the LIKE command will works

```
select name, count(*) as total from String where name like '%hello%' group by name order by total
```

let me know

Comment: Maybe I didn't describe my problem in a good way, but your solution doesn't solve it. What I want is to find all strings which occur inside other strings with the highest frequency. Your query just finds all strings with the word `hello` inside it and counts the amount of each individual string.

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand, your problem is more complicated, sorry